# How to extend styled component MaterialUi types by add TabelCellProps?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I want create styled TableCell component but when I use StyledTableCell in separate file and typescript throut error ts(2322). Typescrip says that I can't use "component","scope", "colSpan" property because it properties doesn't exist in StyledComponent. How should I resolve this problem? ShouldForvardProp doesn't help.

```
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop === 'component',
})(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
})

//StyledTableCell I use in seperate file if I use in the same file there isn't error 

  <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row" colSpan={2}>
```

I tried extend types in this way but it doesn't help me either.

```
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
    },
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
      fontSize: 14,
    },
  })
) as React.ComponentType<TableCellProps> & {
  component?: string;
  scope?: string;
  align?: string;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this -

```ts
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14
  }
}));
```

If you're looking to add some custom props to it -

```ts
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "useStyled"
})<TableCellProps & { useStyled?: boolean }>(({ useStyled, theme }) =>
  useStyled
    ? {
        [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
          color: theme.palette.common.white
        },
        [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
          fontSize: 14
        }
      }
    : {}
);

// Use it like this -
<StyledTableCell useStyled>{child}</StyledTableCell> // Render styled version
<StyledTableCell>{child}</StyledTableCell> // Render normal library version
```

Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-star-ptgk88).

Comment: It's amazing. I spent about 4 hours for this. Thank you.

Comment: @PetroMatkovskyi if I answered your question correctly and your issue is resolved, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.